I am having one text-sql-text project, facing few issues like max_token issue, sometimes wrong answer, result is too slow
I am trying to create a text-sql-text project with a huggingface model and a sample db. I'm getting few issues and doubts, listed right after the code snippet.
Code Snippet:
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import getpass, json
from llama_index.core import PromptTemplate
from typing import List, Tuple
import sqlite3
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "jinaai/jina-reranker-v2-base-multilingual",
    torch_dtype="auto",
    trust_remote_code=True
)

model.to("cpu")  # or 'cpu' if no GPU is available
model.eval()


hf_token="mytoken"

from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceInferenceAPI
mistral_llm = HuggingFaceInferenceAPI(model_name="mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1", token=hf_token)


table_declarations = [
    "CREATE TABLE platform (\n\tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n\tplatform_name TEXT DEFAULT NULL\n);",
    "CREATE TABLE genre (\n\tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n\tgenre_name TEXT DEFAULT NULL\n);",
    "CREATE TABLE publisher (\n\tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n\tpublisher_name TEXT DEFAULT NULL\n);",
    "CREATE TABLE region (\n\tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n\tregion_name TEXT DEFAULT NULL\n);",
    "CREATE TABLE game (\n\tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n\tgenre_id INTEGER,\n\tgame_name TEXT DEFAULT NULL,\n\tCONSTRAINT fk_gm_gen FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genre(id)\n);",
    "CREATE TABLE game_publisher (\n\tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n\tgame_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,\n\tpublisher_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,\n\tCONSTRAINT fk_gpu_gam FOREIGN KEY (game_id) REFERENCES game(id),\n\tCONSTRAINT fk_gpu_pub FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(id)\n);",
    "CREATE TABLE game_platform (\n\tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n\tgame_publisher_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,\n\tplatform_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,\n\trelease_year INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,\n\tCONSTRAINT fk_gpl_gp FOREIGN KEY (game_publisher_id) REFERENCES game_publisher(id),\n\tCONSTRAINT fk_gpl_pla FOREIGN KEY (platform_id) REFERENCES platform(id)\n);",
    "CREATE TABLE region_sales (\n\tregion_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,\n\tgame_platform_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,\n\tnum_sales REAL,\n   CONSTRAINT fk_rs_gp FOREIGN KEY (game_platform_id) REFERENCES game_platform(id),\n\tCONSTRAINT fk_rs_reg FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES region(id)\n);",
]


def rank_tables(query: str, table_specs: List[str], top_n: int = 0) -> List[Tuple[float, str]]:
    """
    Get sorted pairs of scores and table specifications, then return the top N,
    or all if top_n is 0 or default.
    """
    pairs = [[query, table_spec] for table_spec in table_specs]
    scores = model.compute_score(pairs)
    scored_tables = [(score, table_spec) for score, table_spec in zip(scores, table_specs)]
    scored_tables.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
    if top_n and top_n < len(scored_tables):
        return scored_tables[0:top_n]
    return scored_tables


make_sql_prompt_tmpl_text = """
Generate a SQL query to answer the following question from the user:
\"{query_str}\"

The SQL query should use only tables with the following SQL definitions:

Table 1:
{table_1}

Table 2:
{table_2}

Table 3:
{table_3}

Make sure you ONLY output an SQL query and no explanation.
"""
make_sql_prompt_tmpl = PromptTemplate(make_sql_prompt_tmpl_text)


rag_prompt_tmpl_str = """
Use the information in the JSON table to answer the following user query.
Do not explain anything, just answer concisely. Use natural language in your
answer, not computer formatting.

USER QUERY: {query_str}

JSON table:
{json_table}

This table was generated by the following SQL query:
{sql_query}

Answer ONLY using the information in the table and the SQL query, and if the
table does not provide the information to answer the question, answer
"No Information".
"""
rag_prompt_tmpl = PromptTemplate(rag_prompt_tmpl_str)




def answer_sql(user_query: str) -> str:
    try:
        ranked_tables = rank_tables(user_query, table_declarations, top_n=3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ranking failed.\nUser query:\n{user_query}\n\n")
        raise (e)

    make_sql_prompt = make_sql_prompt_tmpl.format(
        query_str=user_query, table_1=ranked_tables[0][1], table_2=ranked_tables[1][1], table_3=ranked_tables[2][1]
    )

    try:
        response = mistral_llm.complete(make_sql_prompt)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"SQL query generation failed\nPrompt:\n{make_sql_prompt}\n\n")
        raise (e)

    # Backslash removal is a necessary hack because sometimes Mistral puts them
    # in its generated code.
    sql_query = str(response).replace("\\", "")

    try:
        sql_response = sqlite3.connect("videogames.db").cursor().execute(sql_query).fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"SQL querying failed. Query:\n{sql_query}\n\n")
        raise (e)

    rag_prompt = rag_prompt_tmpl.format(query_str=user_query, json_table=json.dumps(sql_response), sql_query=sql_query)
    try:
        rag_response = mistral_llm.complete(rag_prompt)
        return str(rag_response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Answer generation failed. Prompt:\n{rag_prompt}\n\n")
        raise (e)
    

print(answer_sql("What is the name of first game?"))

Problems:

How to save and use the current model in this snippet

Getting max_new_tokens error

Input validation error: inputs tokens + max_new_tokens must be <=
32768. Given: 175083 inputs tokens and 256 `max_new_tokens


Result is extremely slow, how to make it super fast?


Please consider me a pure beginner is this field, Thanks is advance!!
